# Conditional Sum/Average/etc... CSV file in Python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, statistics, conditional-statements

First off, I've found similar articles, but I haven't been able to figure out how to translate the answers from those questions to my own problem. Secondly, I'm new to python, so I apologize for being a noob.

Here's my question: **I want to perform conditional calculations (average/proportion/etc..) on values within a text file**

More concretely, I have a file that looks a little something like below

```
0    Diamond    Correct
0    Cross      Incorrect
1    Diamond    Correct
1    Cross      Correct
```

Thus far, I am able to read in the file and collect all of the rows.

```
import pandas as pd
fileLocation = r'C:/Users/Me/Desktop/LogFiles/SubjectData.txt'
df = pd.read_csv(fileLocation, header = None, sep='\t', index_col = False,
                 name = ["Session Number", "Image", "Outcome"])
```

I'm looking to query the file such that I can ask questions like:

--What is the proportion of "Correct" values in the 'Outcome' column when the first column ('Session Number') is 0? So this would be 0.5, because there is one "Correct" and one "Incorrect".

I have other calculations I'd like to perform, but I should be able to figure out where to go once I know how to do this, hopefully simple, command.

Thanks!

Comment: you should search for keywords like: "numpy pandas statistics" or "how calculate statistics pandas" or even "descriptive statistics pandas"..

by searching these terms i've found this excellent article: http://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_dataframe_descriptive_stats.html and also this one http://www.randalolson.com/2012/08/06/statistical-analysis-made-easy-in-python/

Comment: Thanks! This looks like a great resource. I'll reference it as I'm working on my calculations. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also do it this way:

```
In [467]: df.groupby('Session#')['Outcome'].apply(lambda x: (x == 'Correct').sum()/len(x))
Out[467]:
Session#
0    0.5
1    1.0
Name: Outcome, dtype: float64
```

it'll group your DF by `Session#` and calculate `Ratio of correct Outcomes` for each group (`Session#`)

Comment: Oh, wow. This is fantastic! I'm analyzing 100+ data sheets, each formatted identically, but all of which may have different number of sessions. This code is perfect, and give me flexibility when looking across sheets. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

```
# getting the total number of rows
total = len(df)  

# getting the number of rows that have 'Correct' for 'Outcome' and 0 for 'Session Number'
correct_and_session_zero = len(df[(df['Outcome'] == 'Correct') & 
                                  (df['Session Number'] == 0)])

# if you're using python 2 you might need to convert correct_and_session_zero  or total
# to float so you won't lose precision
print(correct_and_session_zero / total)
```